# UIWebView Image Upload reloading webview Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I am using UIWebview to show user profile details. Now when trying to upload the image whole Webview reloading and showing back to the same stage before uploading.

```
UIWebView *ProfileCellWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.layer.frame.size.width, (MainFrame.size.height - 210))];
            [ProfileCellWebview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:USERPROFILEPUBLIC,self.appDelegate.currentUser.userId]];
            NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [ProfileCellWebview setDelegate:self];
            [ProfileCellWebview loadRequest:requestObj];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
            [cell addSubview:ProfileCellWebview];
```

Where i am doing wrong

Comment: Please ask question properly , not able to understand what is issue ?

Comment: trying to upload image from Webview form , after uploading image webview reloading everytime

Comment: can you please able to share url with us ?So we can check it and help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the code to load the url in viewDidLoad. Hope you write the code in viewWillApear or viewDidApper.